# SQL Retest same table that returns 1st row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm a beginner when it comes to sql and this one is a little over my head and hoping someone could point me in the right direction..

I have written a query that correctly returns one row from the right hand table but I need to add another test in the final where clause that rechecks the table and checks all entries in the field `contitems.tofollow` and looks for values greater than zero's which match the original `contracts.ContNo` row returned..

```
SELECT Contracts.*, Contitems.*
FROM   dbo.Contracts 
INNER JOIN dbo.ContItems 
 ON dbo.ContItems.RECID =       
  (SELECT TOP(1) RECID 
   FROM dbo.ContItems 
   WHERE (ContItems.CONTNO = dbo.Contracts.CONTNO))
WHERE  dbo.Contracts.SOURCE = 2 
 and (contracts.custom = 1 or contitems.tofollow > 0) 
 and contracts.status not in (4,9)
```

I need to replace the `contitems.tofollow > 0` with a test that rechecks the whole `contitems.tofollow` results for each `ContNO` but no idea how to achieve it.. can anyone help..?

Comment: `select top 1` without an `order by` clause is going to retrieve whichever row is most convenient for SQL Server to retrieve *at that time* - the result could vary between two runs of the query.

Comment: thanks Ocaso..been out this morning so sorry for the late reply.. The Top 1 result it picks doesn't matter as long as it's just the one line I need.. however I need to retest the same table in the final where clause and not sure how to tackle it.. the contitems.tofollow > 0 statement is just testing the returned single line.. I need to test all entries in the contitems table matching the original ContItems.CONTNO = dbo.Contracts.CONTNO

Answer (score 0):

i thought of another way to do this by selecting the single row with the greatest TOFOLLOW quantity -- no further test necessary..

```
   SELECT Contracts.*, Contitems.*
   FROM   dbo.Contracts 
   INNER JOIN dbo.ContItems 
   ON dbo.ContItems.RECID =       
  (SELECT TOP(1) RECID 
  FROM dbo.ContItems 
  WHERE (ContItems.CONTNO = dbo.Contracts.CONTNO)
   ORDER BY TOFOLLOW Desc)
 WHERE  dbo.Contracts.SOURCE = 2 
 and (contracts.custom = 1 or contitems.tofollow > 0)
```